# Ejected expo react native app requires expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I created a RN with create-react-native-app, and I have now decided to eject. It didn't work initially, and required some packages to be installed (@babel/...), but now, it complains that `Module 'expo' does not exist in the Haste module map`.

Why does it still require expo, now that it has been ejected? Or have I misunderstood what ejection does?

N.B. during the ejection I chose the option to eject to an RN app, not to ExpoKit. This is on iOS, currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ejecting `expo` app you'll be asked about using `expo-kit` or just `react-native` and it's up to you to choose, plus `Module 'expo' does not exist in the Haste module map` means you still using `expo` in your code so double check your code to be sure that you're not importing `expo` anywhere and try again.

**TL;DR**

Ejected expo react native app requires expo? the short answer is no.

when using `expo` app you have the ability to build your app using the `expo` server so you don't have to have `Android Studio` or `XCode` installed all you have to do is `$ expo build:[android|ios]` and download your built package after the build process is done also you can run your app using expo client app on Android and Ios but once ejecting you'll lose the ability of using expo server as your build environment instead you have to use `Android Studio` or `XCode`, but the main difference here is when you choose `expo-kit` you still have the ability of using expo client to run your app and you still have the ability to use expo modules inside your code but when you choose `react-native` you can't use expo client instead you have to use the native tools, anyway in all cases once you eject your project you have to build it yourself and you can't undo this step.

**Sidenote**

You can build very powerful apps using only JavaScript without any need to eject especially when using `expo SDK 31+, I'm working on an app now with features like detecting location, live maps, social login and chat and I don't need to eject it at all.

Please take a look [here](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v31-0-0-is-now-available-cad6d0463f49) and [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/)

**Update:**

One last thing you have to remember is that when using `expo` or `expo-kit` you can keep developing `ios` app on any OS but when using `react-native` you can't do this you **MUST** have a mac.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Unfortunately, I need both the camera, and bluetooth, so I'm pretty sure I need to eject in one way or the other. It seems that the dependencies file is full of expo related stuff (babel-preset-expo) etc. Shouldn't the eject script remove these deps?

Comment: No, as noted in the documentation when ejecting you have to refactor your code yourself.